# Mysql WHERE not working in table with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, entity-attribute-value

I am developing a EAV system for multiple entities (Product, Company,...)
I will tell the problem at the end.

The database structure is the following:

**EAV_ENTITY**

This table will give me a list of all available Entities, like:

```
1 | Product
2 | Company
```

Structure:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**EAV_ATTRIBUTE**

This table have a list of attributes, the ref is a mnemonic for getting the attributes by query easier. I add here the entity_type_id that is related with the table eav_entity because I want to limit each attribute to only one entity.

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ref            | varchar(50)      | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| name           | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI |         |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**EAV_VALUE**

This table have the values related to the attribute, values would be: red, green, orange, for attribute "color"

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| attribute_id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value           | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**EAV_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE**

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_id      | int(11) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| entity_type_id | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value_id       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here I make all the "magic", I make a query making a relation between an entity(type, id) and all the values related and the attribute that the value belongs to.

My query is this one

```
SELECT
    e.model,
    av.entity_id,
    a.id as category_id,
    a.ref as category_ref,
    v.id as value_id

FROM eav_entity as e

RIGHT JOIN eav_attribute_value as av
ON e.id = av.entity_type_id

LEFT JOIN eav_value as v
ON v.id = av.value_id

LEFT JOIN eav_attribute as a
ON v.attribute_id = a.id

WHERE e.model = 'App\Product'
```

**PROBLEM & QUESTION**

When I add the statement WHERE e.model ='Whatever' I dont get any result.
And it is supposed to be filter. But without the WHERE statement I get the results as expected. 
I think that it might be a problem related to the way I am doing the joins.

A real example without WHERE e.model

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+
| model       | entity_id | category_id | category_ref              | value_id |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+
| App\Product |        13 |           2 | product_development_phase |        2 |
| App\Product |        13 |           2 | product_development_phase |        3 |
| App\Product |        13 |           4 | product_therapeutics      |       58 |
| App\Company |        13 |           4 | product_therapeutics      |       58 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Try `WHERE e.model = 'App\\Product'`

Comment: @Uueerdo post it as answer, it solved my question, many thanks!

Comment: I don't use outer joins myself but don't you want to make `e.model = 'App\\Product'` part of the join search condition rather than the `WHERE`?

Comment: @onedaywhen It will also work,  because the WHERE statement filters the result from the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Uuerdo said, I need to add a second backslash as escape character to interpret the second one as a real backslash.

The query will result in the next below:

```
SELECT
    e.model,
    av.entity_id,
    a.id as category_id,
    a.ref as category_ref,
    v.id as value_id

FROM eav_entity as e

RIGHT JOIN eav_attribute_value as av
    ON e.id = av.entity_type_id

LEFT JOIN eav_value as v
    ON v.id = av.value_id

LEFT JOIN eav_attribute as a
    ON v.attribute_id = a.id

WHERE e.model = "App\\Product"
```

Comment: Feel free to mark your final query here as the accepted answer; I didn't have time to make a elaborated answer with an explanation.